# Topological space $X$ has no subbasis $S$ with property $Card(S)\leq Card(X)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and infinite which has no subbasis $S$ with property $Card(S)\leq Card(X)$.

What special properties does it has?
For example it's not metrizable.

Because the metrizable spaces have subbasis with cardinal not grater than cardinal of space.

Does exist any paper about it?

Comment: For an infinite topological space $X$, "$X$ has no subbase of cardinality $\le\operatorname{Card}(X)$" is equivalent to "$X$ has no base of cardinality $\le\operatorname{Card}(X)$" and also to "some point of $X$ has no neighborhood base of cardinality $\le\operatorname{Card}(X)$."

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter whether you consider the size of a minimal base or a subbase because they are the same (for infinite bases/subbases): if we have a subbase of size $\kappa$, its generated base (using finite intersections) is also of size $\kappa$.

The weight $w(X)$ of a space $X$ is defined as the minimal size of a base for $X$. So you are asking for spaces with $w(X) > |X|$. As bof rightly remarks in his comment, this means that there is at least one point $p \in X$ so that $p$ has no neighbourhood base of size $ \le |X|$ (for otherwise we'd have a base of size |X| by collecting all local bases at all points of $X$ together, if they'd all have size $\le |X|$).

I'm not aware of any papers on these spaces in particular (as a class). Examples include ultrafilter spaces, countable dense subspaces of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$, etc. No such space can be metrisable, locally compact, or orderable.